# Why is 对...不置一词 used like this?

Tags: word-choice

该声明对东盟一些成员国长期以来在南海的大规模填海造地和军事建设活动不置一词。
I am having trouble with 对...不置一词。 So apparently, the sentence translates to, "This statement is not saying anything to stuff the ASEAN member nations have been doing for a long time."  However, the article was about how the Chinese were against other countries doing stuff in their territories.

Why is `对...不置一词` used here? Does it have a different meaning in this context?

Comment: article is about Chinese Foreign Ministry spokesperson Hong Lei（外交部发言人洪磊）＇s reaction to the ASEAN summit conference chairperson statement （东盟峰会发表主席声明）， it seems only natural that each side only complains about the other side＇s construction in disputed waters （and keeps silent about their own construction activities）

Answer (score 3):

对..不置一词 literally means to 'not place a word on...'.  As Pedroski suggested, it means to not making a comment (or even a word) about the incident.

Answer (score 1):

I looked up '不置一词‘ in iciba. It says 'not to speak a single word, keep silence, not make a comment'

Comment: "keep silence, not make a comment" are right.